# SQL select max value in a group

Tags: sql

I'm stuck on this for days now. I have 3 fields, tot_order, slsnum and ordernum. I need to get the max value in ordernum, which is a unique field and its total order number in the ordernum field. The slsnum field is based on a date, so I could have a slsnum# 18443450 repeatedly per row.

tot_order:
    240,
    100,
     50

ordernum: 23006343,
   220110021,
   180872124

I need the end result like this:
tot_order: 240 slsnum: 18443450 ordernum: 23006343

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... GROUP BY...) anothertable WHERE ordernum = MAX(ordernum);

Comment: how can i select the corresponding "tot_order" of a max "ordernum" if the slsnum is not a unique value, meaning it's based on transaction date? so i could have slsnum "1234567" showing 10xs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
SELECT tot_order, slsnum, ordernum
FROM table as t1
WHERE ordernum = (SELECT max(ordernum) FROM table as t2 WHERE t2.slsnum = t1.slsnum)
```

That subquery in the `WHERE` clause references the `slsnum` field in the main query to grab the `max(ordernum)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following query:

```
Select tot_order, slsnum, ordernum
from table as t
where ordernum>=ALL(
     Select ordernum from t
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl..

```
SELECT tot_order, slsnum, ordernum
FROM YourTable
WHERE OrderNum = (SELECT Max(OrderNum) FROM YourTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
from table_name
where ordernum = (
  select max(ordernum) from table 
)
```